# g++ compilation failed; only default headers seem to be the problem

Tags: gcc, g++, gnu-make

This seems like a problem that's really hard to google! Which is why I finally came here after so long. I was compiling the updated [Half-Life SDK](https://github.com/SamVanheer/halflife-updated), and I get approx. 4000 lines of errors, all within default headers/

I tried reinstalling g++-multilib, being the primary dependency listed, but evidently it didn't help. I also tried any gcc packages I thought of, none of which worked.

Compiling under latest Ubuntu stable.

[Full Log](https://gist.github.com/JuliaAllen1/fa8c7a2cedd162281f4ae020a9b68a6e)

Comment: This is not a full log. There are no commands.

Comment: @n.m. updated to include commands. initial command was `make`

Comment: Don't know, your install may be broken. Can you compile any c++ program with `#include <cmath>` in it?

Comment: @n.m I cannot, no. I get similar errors to above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually replacing `math.h`. I'm not sure if this is advisable, only that it did in fact work in my case.